# Google Speech API Python not responding

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm trying to implement google's speech api but every time I try to run the program, the terminal goes unresponsive. It seems that the program runs until the line "response = client.recognize(config, audio)" and just gets stuck at that point. Here's a picture of my code, I pulled most of it straight from google's cloud platform documentation.

```
def transcribe_file(speech_file):

    import os
    import io
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="api-key.json"

    """Transcribe the given audio file."""
    from google.cloud import speech
    from google.cloud.speech import enums
    from google.cloud.speech import types
    import io
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    with io.open(speech_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
        content = audio_file.read()

    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding='FLAC',
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US')

    print(config)

    response = client.recognize(config, audio)

    # Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
    # them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
    for result in response.results:
        # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.
        print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))

transcribe_file(audio/file/name.wav)
```

Comment: How long is your audio file?

Comment: ~20 seconds long. It used to be mp3 and I converted it on audacity to wav.

Comment: There might be something in your environment which causes this behavior. I've tried the same script using my audio file in Cloud Shell and it worked just fine.

Comment: What could be the issue with my environment? I'm using a virtual env on my local computer and downloaded the speech API libraries as well as initialized google sdk. how can I run this script in cloud shell?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when building my app with PyInstaller. Make sure you have
the **certifi** folder with the file **cacert.pem** in it. Those should come with the library when you run `pip install google-cloud-speech`. If not reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, tried changing

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="api-key.json"
```

to

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]= r"full/path/api-key.json"
```

on *window*.